# Does Corda V2 offer E-Wallet or individual account creation support?

Tags: corda

Does Corda V2 support individual account creation or e-wallet integration? This seems to be something that was being talked about and I can't seem to find anything definitive.  There are some work arounds  that we could implement but wonder if there this has already been handled.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality hasn't been added to Corda at this time.